# proFTPD install mod_exec

Tags: debian, proftpd

For dummys please:

I need to install proFTPD module mod_exec on a debian squeeze (64bit).
How does it work. The documentation on the proftpd page was no help for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling the source is the only way to get it right. By the way you'll get the latest version with important bugfixes. I've done this with these steps:

```
# install build-tools and dependencies:
aptitude install build-essential gettext make g++ libwrap0-dev libldap2-dev libmysql++-dev libpam0g-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev unixodbc-dev libncurses5-dev libacl1-dev libcap-dev

# download sources:
wget ftp://ftp.proftpd.org/distrib/source/proftpd-1.3.3e.tar.gz
tar -xvf proftpd-1.3.3e.tar.gz
cd proftpd-1.3.3e

# add missing module mod_vroot
cd contrib/
wget http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/modules/proftpd-mod-vroot-0.9.2.tar.gz
tar -xvf proftpd-mod-vroot-0.9.2.tar.gz
cd ..

# configure, make and install:
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-includes=/usr/include/postgresql:/usr/include/mysql --mandir=/usr/share/man --sysconfdir=/etc/proftpd --localstatedir=/var/run --libexecdir=/usr/lib/proftpd --enable-sendfile --enable-facl --enable-dso --enable-autoshadow --enable-ctrls --with-modules=mod_readme:mod_sql:mod_sql_postgres:mod_exec --enable-ipv6 --enable-nls --build x86_64-linux-gnu --with-shared=mod_unique_id:mod_site_misc:mod_load:mod_ban:mod_quotatab:mod_sql:mod_sql_mysql:mod_sql_postgres:mod_sql_sqlite:mod_sql_odbc:mod_dynmasq:mod_quotatab_sql:mod_ldap:mod_quotatab_ldap:mod_ratio:mod_tls:mod_rewrite:mod_radius:mod_wrap:mod_wrap2:mod_wrap2_file:mod_wrap2_sql:mod_quotatab_file:mod_quotatab_radius:mod_facl:mod_ctrls_admin:mod_vroot:mod_sftp:mod_sftp_pam:mod_sftp_sql:mod_shaper:mod_sql_passwd:mod_ifsession build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu CFLAGS=-O2
make
make install
```

I've used --with-modules=mod_readme:mod_sql:mod_sql_postgres:mod_exec to also include mod_sql with postgres which is maybe not necessary because it's in the --with-shared part.

Answer (score 0):

Odd. On my debian squeeze system it is available by default:

```
$ dpkg -L proftpd-basic | grep exec
/usr/lib/proftpd/mod_exec.so
```

with

```
$ apt-cache policy proftpd-basic
proftpd-basic:
  Installed: 1.3.3a-6squeeze6
  Candidate: 1.3.3a-6squeeze6
  Version table:
     1.3.5~rc1-2 0
         -1 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ experimental/main amd64 Packages
     1.3.4a-3 0
        200 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
        100 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.3.3a-6squeeze6 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.3.3a-6squeeze4 0
        500 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main amd64 Packages
```